# how to fetch top 7 on basis of score from List<Object> java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of objects `List<FileNameAndScoreDTO> fileNameAndScoreList = new ArrayList<>();`
I want to access the top 7 **names of files** on the basis of **scores**.

**FileNameAndScoreDTO.java**

```
public class FileNameAndScoreDTO {
    String file_name;
    int score;
    long category;
}
```

whereas the **category** could be **breakfast,lunch or dinner**.
I want a total of **21 file names** on the basis of **highest scores** in which 7 file names of breakfast,7 of lunch and 7 of dinner.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: How can the `category` be `breakfast`? It's an attribute of type `long`.

Comment: If category is limited to only 3 different values, why not use an enum instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i'd recommend to use a `String` for the category or even better an `Enum`.

I assumed you want it in descending order to get the seven file names with the highest score.

The method below filters for the given category, sorts the leftover objects by the score in descending order, limits the amount of objects to 7 and returns their filenames as `List<String>`

```java
public List<String> getTopSevenNamesOrderedByScoreDescOfCategory(List<FileNameAndScoreDTO> fullList, long category){
    return fullList.stream()
        .filter(f -> Long.compare(f.getCategory(), category) == 0)
        .sorted((f1, f2) -> Integer.compare(f2.getScore(), f1.getScore()))
        .limit(7)
        .map(f -> f.getFile_name())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can call the function like this. The first parameter is the list with all objects. The second parameter is the number(?) of the category.

```java
List<String> topSevenNamesOrderedByScoreWithCategory1337 = getTopSevenNamesOrderedByScoreDescOfCategory(fileNameAndScoreList, 0l);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,

Comment: I want to confirm that the names are returning on the bases of Top scores ???

Comment: @Lily Yes, have a look at `.sorted()`. It compares the scores of each object in the list. By entering `f2.getScore()` as first instead of second parameter you reverse the list. So basically you already have the 7 file names with the highest score.